# I have a Name error in python 3, it is with the variable "userMessage"

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, input, nameerror

```py
#Start
def main():
    #variables
    encryptedMessage=""
    userMessage = input("you're message here: ")
    shift=5
    #for loop
    for character in userMessage:
        #5:50AM February 24th, 2020
        eN = ord(character)
        eN+= shift
        encryptedMessage += chr(eN)
main()
print(userMessage)
print(encrytedMessage)
```

I have been in python a year now and never got this error mainly because I don't use for loops. when I use userMessage in print or for the for loop there's an error. I have tried resolving this using global, but it did not work so I simply removed it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eshan/Downloads/cypher.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(userMessage)
NameError: name 'userMessage' is not defined
```

Comment: `userMessage` is a local variable in `main()` function. You're trying to print it outside function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to print the value which is local variable, outside the function because of which you are getting "userMessage" not defined error.
You need to declare the variable as global and need to initiate it if you want to use it outside your function